# How to properly downgrade PHP 5.5 to 5.3 on Centos 6.4

Tags: php, centos6.4

I installed Centos_6.4 and have about 2 weeks work into setting up my environment and servers on it. So I get to my Kayako support suite and it wont install and they say I have to use PHP 5.3

I have searched for hours and tried every suggestion could find and at the end of all attempts PHpstill shows 5.5 and Im stumped.
How do I downgrade PHP 5.5 to 5.3 on CentOS 6.4 64bit server

Comment: What steps did you try?

Comment: CentOS 6.4 comes with PHP 5.3 already. How did you end up with PHP 5.5?